# Jersey 1.17 download large files

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to download large files from REST service, I have code:

```
@GET
@Path("/laboDownloadAnyType")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response laboDownload() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final String fileName = "SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4";
    final InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    return Response.ok(fileInStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" ) //optional
      .build();
}
```

and when I'm using small files it works really great, but now I want to download large file (from 500MB to 3GB) I'm getting

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use FTP for large files if possible. Obviously you try to hold the whole file in memory ... avoid that.

Comment: Ah, wait. Codesnippet is Server-Side ... I think I remember that there was a streaming solution.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.bhaveshthaker.com/22/sending-transfering-pushing-files-in-multiparts-chunks-from-server-to-client-with-restful-web-services-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Use MappedByteBuffer instead of InputStream , you can check the implementation of MappedByteBuffer here [Check this link](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/nio/java-nio-2-0-memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer-tutorial/)

Hope it provide you the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
I had to turn off Comunication Logging